# Pass custom variables to android widget

Tags: android, widget

I have a Widget defined in xml and java. To initialise it, I use:

```
LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(...)
```

which automatically calls the constructor

```
public Widget(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
```

How can I pass more parameters, say, a String, to this constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Create a CustomWidget class that extends the Widget class and create the constructor that receives the same as the super class but also the String you want.

Don't forget to call `super(context, attrs);`